# Applying function to vectors row by row

Tags: matlab, function, loops, vector

I'm trying to apply a function to a vector where for each new row the same function applies but a variable changes. So for example if I have a vector with `N` rows:

```
A = [1.2; 1.5; 1.8; 2.3; 2.7; 2.8; 2.9];
```

I want to subtract `n*0.1` away from each row where `n = row number`. So `1.5` in row 2 would be subtracted by `0.2 (2*0.1)`, `2.8` in row 6 would be subtracted by `0.6 (0.1*6)`, and so on.

To clarify I would like a function that says to my file, OK this is row `n` and I want to subtract the number in row `n` by `n` multiplied by `0.1`. I would like the code to be able to read the file row by row so the end result is a vector that has done the above to each row. I think a loop would be needed?

I'm sure the solution is simple but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
A
    1.2000
    1.5000
    1.8000
    2.3000
    2.7000
    2.8000
    2.9000

b = A-(1:numel(A)).'*0.1
b =
    1.1000
    1.3000
    1.5000
    1.9000
    2.2000
    2.2000
    2.2000
```

What it does is it creates a column vector with values `1:numel(A)`, so `[1; 2; 3 ...]`, then multiplies each of these values by `0.1`. This vector is then subtracted from the original vector.

As you see, there is a dot, `.'`, in there. It is not really necessary here, but it's good practice to include it. Without the dot, `'` would make a [conjugate transpose](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), in stead of a [regular one](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). The transpose of course, converts the horizontal vector to a vertical one.

To satisfy [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar), who can make dinner and build a house at the same time using only `bsxfun, permute and reshape`:

If you wanted to do this with a matrix instead, you could use [`repmat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html), or [`meshgrid`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), or the much more awesome [`bsxfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), like this:

```
A = magic(5);

b = bsxfun(@minus, A, [1:size(A,1)].'*0.1)
b =
   16.9000   23.9000    0.9000    7.9000   14.9000
   22.8000    4.8000    6.8000   13.8000   15.8000
    3.7000    5.7000   12.7000   19.7000   21.7000
    9.6000   11.6000   18.6000   20.6000    2.6000
   10.5000   17.5000   24.5000    1.5000    8.5000
```

More dimensions? Combine `bsxfun` and [`permute`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html).

Comment: and `bsxfun` for a *proper* matrix case, though not asked!

Comment: haha lovely comment about dinner and house, maybe mansion someday ;)