# MATLAB how to apply a function to cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, cell-array

I have the following cell array:

```
<20x2>
<32x2>
<28x2>
<30x2>
```

What I am trying to do is read into `row 1` of the cell array which is `<20x2>` and once I am in `<20x2>` I would like to apply the following function to the first column only.

In the first one I would like every row of `column 1` in `C{1,1}` to be subtracted by 0.1. In the second one `C{2,1}` (`<32x2>`) I would like every row of column 1 to be subtracted by 0.2 and so on...

So to clarify I am trying to subtract `n*0.1` from the first column of each submatrix in the cell array where `n= row number of the cell array`. So if there was a section in the cell array in `row 8`, `column 1` would be subtracted by `8*0.1 = 0.8`

I hope the question is clear enough, I have tried to word it as clear as I can.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions

Attempt

```
First = C{1,1}(:,1);
Subtraction = First - 0.1
```

Gives me my desired result but only for row 1 of my cell array.

Unique question to [Applying function to vectors row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761058/matlab-applying-function-to-vectors-row-by-row/32761226#32761226) because this involves a cell array as opposed to a matrix. The aspect of reading into a cell array makes it a different variant of the problem so if somebody was having a similar problem to this question the mentioned 'duplicate' question would not help, especially with little MATLAB knowledge like myself

Comment: Have you tried anything? Using loops perhaps?

Comment: I can do what I am asking if I just had a nx2 matrix but struggling to read into a cell array where n changes

Comment: You need to post some code to show that you have attempted to solve it yourself... why can you just go `...-n*0.1;...` where `n` is your `for`-loop variable?

Comment: Didn't include my attempt because it's a pretty pathetic effort. I have thought I need a loop. 1. I don't know how to apply the loop and 2. I really don't know how to call that n is changing so matlab reads through the entirety of my file

Comment: No, it's a different end goal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to adapt your attempt to a loop:

```
for n = 1:size(c,1)
    C{n,1}(:,1) = C{n,1}(:,1) - n*0.1;
end
```